# Django sentry installation error

Tags: django, sentry

I am trying to install django sentry for my application but got below error at the time of installation:-

```
In file included from Modules/_billiard/multiprocessing.c:9:
Modules/_billiard/multiprocessing.h:12:20: error: Python.h: No such file or directory
Modules/_billiard/multiprocessing.h:13:26: error: structmember.h: No such file or directory
Modules/_billiard/multiprocessing.h:14:22: error: pythread.h: No such file or directory
In file included from Modules/_billiard/multiprocessing.c:9:
Modules/_billiard/multiprocessing.h:127: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
Modules/_billiard/multiprocessing.h:133: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
Modules/_billiard/multiprocessing.h:134: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
Modules/_billiard/multiprocessing.h:135: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
Modules/_billiard/multiprocessing.h:136: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
Modules/_billiard/multiprocessing.h:137: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘BilliardSemLockType’
Modules/_billiard/multiprocessing.h:138: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘BilliardConnectionType’
Modules/_billiard/multiprocessing.h:139: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘BilliardPipeConnectionType’
Modules/_billiard/multiprocessing.h:171: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘PyObject_HEAD’
Modules/_billiard/multiprocessing.c:17: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
Modules/_billiard/multiprocessing.c:19: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
Modules/_billiard/multiprocessing.c:20: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
Modules/_billiard/multiprocessing.c:26: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
Modules/_billiard/multiprocessing.c:101: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
Modules/_billiard/multiprocessing.c:136: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
Modules/_billiard/multiprocessing.c:181: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
Modules/_billiard/multiprocessing.c:199: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘Billiard_module_methods’
Modules/_billiard/multiprocessing.c:222: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘init_billiard’
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Django version is 1.2.5 and python is 2.6. I have tried(easy_install, pip, download and install) all the ways, But remains same error.

Please anyone advise on this.

Comment: That just means the compilation failed - you need to be more specific. There should be a more specific error somewhere

Comment: i have updated the error content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that GCC can't find Python header files.

If you are using Python installed by some kind of a package system try installing Python's developer package. It should be named python-dev or something along the lines.